# Click event not always working in Cycle.js

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I have some problems with my first cycle.js app.
Everything in my component works fine, but the click event in this isolated component is behaving irregularly. By clicking `.filter__toggle` the `.filter` element which is rendered in renderHeader should change its class but it is not working on every click.
Here's the code, any ideas?

```js
export default ({DOM, results$, props$}) => {
  // what to show on start
  const initialResults$ = props$.map(props => props.initial).first();
  // data from the db
  const newResults$ = results$.withLatestFrom(
    props$,
    (results, props) => _.filter(results, (o) => o.type === props.type )
  );
  // mix of initial and new values
  const body$ = initialResults$.concat(newResults$);
  // block title
  const title$ = props$.map(props => props.title).first();
  // click events from the filter toggler
  const filter$ = DOM.select('.filter__toggle')
    .events('click')
    .startWith(false)
    .scan((prev, next) => !prev);


  // view elements
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  const headerTree$ = Observable
    .combineLatest(title$, filter$, (title, state) => {
      return renderHeader(title, state);
    });

  const bodyTree$ = body$.map(body => {
    return div('.m-space-items-top-2.m-space-h-2', body.map(item =>
      renderItem(item.title, item.url)
    ));
  });

  const vtree$ = Observable.combineLatest(headerTree$, bodyTree$, (headerElement, bodyElement) => {
    return section('.menu__block', [
      headerElement,
      bodyElement
    ]);
  });

  return {
    DOM: vtree$
  };
};

function renderHeader(title, filter){
  return header('.f-meta.filter' + (filter ? '.is-active' : ''), [
    div('.filter__header', h1([
        title,
        button('.filter__toggle', [
          svg('svg', {'class': 'u-icon', 'width': 10, 'height': 10},
            svg('use', {'xlink:href': '#icon-arrow'})
          )
        ])
      ]
    )),
    div('.filter__container', [...])
  ]);
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like the problem was based on using an outdated version of the library.